# How to eliminate spacing in tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, graphics, standalone, crop

It seems that, when using `Tikz`, nodes and/or the `tikzpicture` environment add space around a drawing. An example is shown in the following MWE, where a simple square is drawn three times. First it is drawn in just a single `tikzpicture`, then in a nested `tikzpicture`, and finally in a nested `tikzpicture` with the `inner sep` adjusted. This last image makes me suspect there are some widths that need to be set to zero.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\standaloneenv{tikzpicture} % New page for every image
% The code for the square
\newcommand\Square[1][]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[#1]
        \draw (0,0)--(1,0)--(1,1)--(0,1)--cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\begin{document}
% Image with correct cropping
\Square[x=1.5cm,y=1.5cm]
% Image with a lot of space
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0,0){
        \Square[x=1.5cm,y=1.5cm]
        };
\end{tikzpicture}
% Image with some cropping
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[inner sep=0pt] at (0,0){
        \Square[x=1.5cm,y=1.5cm]
        };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The three output images (or pages) are the following.

[image]

How does one eliminate this spacing? Nesting these environments is necessary for the specific problem I'm working on, and `\includegraphics[clip]{}` doesn't work in combination with `\standaloneenv{tikzpicture}` (which was tried just in case the `standalone` failed at cropping).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have spurious spaces in the definition of `\Square`:

```
\newcommand\Square[1][]{% <--- a space was here
    \begin{tikzpicture}[#1]
        \draw (0,0)--(1,0)--(1,1)--(0,1)--cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}% <--- a space was here
    }
```

Here's what I get after changing the definition:

[image]

The first of your squares came out good because TeX is in "vertical mode" and so it ignores the first space; then it does `\par` and so also the final one gets ignored. In the other two cases, the spaces are already inside a `tikzpicture`, so they aren't ignored any more.

Comment: This is fantastic. Hours of attempting different cropping packages and documentclasses (standalone, preview, crop..), changing parameters of `node` and `tikzpicture` etc, and then it turns out to be a white space. Thanks!