# Controlling the whitespace padding around tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, wrapfigure

I'm sure this has been asked here, but I can't seem to find a **simple** solution. I would like to use the [wrapfigure](/questions/tagged/wrapfigure) environment to place a tikzfigure on the side of my text, as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0pt}%
    \vspace{-1cm}% Doesn't do anything
    \begin{tikzpicture}%
    [every node/.style={inner sep=0,outer sep=0}]%There are no nodes, so doesn't do anything
        \foreach \z in {0,6,...,36}%
            \shade[ball color=blue] (0,\z pt) circle (3pt);%
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[2-3]

\end{document}
```

which gives

[image: Zoom in of spacing around blue spheres and text]

The problem is that there is (IMHO) too much spacing above and below the text. When using `inludegraphics` I can add `vspace` to nudge it into place. However with `tikzpicture`, this doesn't work.

I found multiple questions (*e.g.* [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57484/is-there-a-way-to-control-whitespace-around-a-tikz-picture), [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111194/how-to-eliminate-spacing-in-tikzpicture)) that deal with spacing around objects defined with `\newcommand`. Others dealt with spacing around `node`s, which is not relevant here (and doesn't help anyway).

Is there a *simple* way to control the padding around a `tikzpicture`? (Closing as duplicate would be welcome)

Comment: Hello! This has nothing to do with TikZ, it's a property (hardcoded, as far as I remember) of `wrapfig`. You can verify this by replacing your `tikzpicture` with `\rule{5mm}{2cm}`. Also, you can use `\vspace`, you just have to add a star: `\vspace*{-1cm}`. However, it's not quite a good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a width of `0pt`, use a reasonable value like `5/6pt`. And give a suitable value for the number of lines the picture will span (`[4]` here)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{wrapfigure}[4]{r}{7pt}%
    \vspace*{-4mm}% This works now
    \begin{tikzpicture}%
    [every node/.style={inner sep=0,outer sep=0}]%There are no nodes, so doesn't do anything
        \foreach \z in {0,6,...,36}%
            \shade[ball color=blue] (0,\z pt) circle (3pt);%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[2]


Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi.
\begin{wrapfigure}[4]{r}{7pt}%
    \vspace*{-4mm}% This works now
    \begin{tikzpicture}%
    [every node/.style={inner sep=0,outer sep=0}]%There are no nodes, so doesn't do anything
        \foreach \z in {0,6,...,36}%
            \shade[ball color=blue] (0,\z pt) circle (3pt);%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{wrapfigure}
Morbi
auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies
et, tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum, erat ligula aliquet
magna, vitae ornare odio metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis.
Suspendisse ut massa. Cras nec ante. Pellentesque a nulla. Cum sociis
natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
Aliquam tincidunt urna. Nulla ullamcorper vestibulum turpis. Pellentesque
cursus luctus mauris.

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can put the picture in a box and use the width of that box like below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newsavebox{\mypicture}
\sbox{\mypicture}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}%
    [every node/.style={inner sep=0,outer sep=0}]%There are no nodes, so doesn't do anything
        \foreach \z in {0,6,...,36}%
            \shade[ball color=blue] (0,\z pt) circle (3pt);%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    }

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{wrapfigure}[4]{r}{\wd\mypicture}%
    \vspace*{-4mm}% This works now
    \usebox{\mypicture}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[2]


Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi.
\begin{wrapfigure}[4]{r}{\wd\mypicture}%
    \vspace*{-4mm}% This works now
    \usebox{\mypicture}
\end{wrapfigure}
Morbi
auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies
et, tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum, erat ligula aliquet
magna, vitae ornare odio metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis.
Suspendisse ut massa. Cras nec ante. Pellentesque a nulla. Cum sociis
natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
Aliquam tincidunt urna. Nulla ullamcorper vestibulum turpis. Pellentesque
cursus luctus mauris.

\end{document}
```

Comment: So every time I change the picture I have to readjust the width...

Comment: @AviGinsburg: Yes. Think of different images with different width. That will trouble TeX in accomodating them.

Comment: Usually I control the width with {0.x\textwidth} or similar, causing the image to scale. This doesn't work with `tikzpicture`s. Is there a way to pass the width of the `tikzpicture` to the `wrapfigure`?

Comment: @AviGinsburg: Please see the edit. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, but... feels so hacky. Each figure now has its own box. Well, I guess that's what I asked for.